# como enviar parámetros de un input dentro de un ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directivas, angularjs-scope

```
 <div class="list-group">
  <div ng-repeat="p in Productos | orderBy:'Nombre' | filter:search "  class="list-group-item"  >
    <tr>
    <td>
    {{ p.Nombre }} - USD {{ p.Precio }} <br> 
    </td>
    <td> <i class="fa fa-plus-square " ></i> <i class="fa fa-plus-square pull-center " ></i>
      <input type="number" ng-model="cantidadn" min="1">
                <button ng-click="agregaproducto(p)" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-right">Agregar</button> 
            </td>

    </tr>
  </div>

</div>
```

> Cita en bloque

```
 $scope.agregaproducto = function(prod) {

        restApi.call({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'pedido/agregar',
            data: {
            Pedido_id: $routeParams.id,
            Producto_id: prod.id,
            Cantidad: $scope.cantidadn,
            PrecioUnitario: prod.Precio,
            Total:$scope.cantidadn * prod.Precio
            },
            response: function (r) {

                if (r.response!=true) {
                     alert(r.message);
                } else {
              obtener2();

                }

            },
            error: function (r) {

            },
            validationError: function (r) {

            }

        });

    }
```

> Cita en bloque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que explicar lo que quieres. No podemos adivinar.

Comment: hola Einer y gracias por la ayuda, como puedo enviar el valor del input con directiva ng-repeat

Comment: Que es lo que quieres enviar? A donde quieres enviarlo? Que has intentado? Has tenido algun error? Se especifico en tu pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: estoy enviando los valores con una funcion ng-click="agregaproducto(p)" que me trae el ng-repeat , pero tengo un campo de texto que no formar parte del de los valores que me devuelve el ng-ng-repeat, y quiero devolver ese valor al controlador

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo agrega una propiedad cualquiera al `ngModel` del input y angular se encargara de agregarla al objeto `p`:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  
  $scope.productos = [
    {id:1},
    {id:2}
  ];
  
  $scope.agregaproducto= function(p) {
    alert(p.nombreProducto);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">

  <div ng-repeat='p in productos'>
    
    <input value="" ng-model="p.nombreProducto" />
    
    <input type="button" ng-click="agregaproducto(p)" value="Enviar"/>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas  Gracias Gracias